# Whether the `--cpus` means logical CPU processors?

Tags: docker

When I read [document](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#configure-the-default-cfs-scheduler), there have param `--cpus`
whether the `cpus` means the logic CPU processor (not physical CPU nor CPU core)?

Comment: How would you have 1.5 physical CPU's/Cores?

Comment: According to this forum discussion, they refer to "logical" cores. https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-cpu-option-with-hyperthreading/112664

Comment: @user550701 I'm very familiar with the implementation, I'm trying to understand the OP's confusion after they looked at the documentation. Having 1.5 physical CPUs doesn't make sense, so the question itself is unexpected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unit "1 CPU" refers to 1 logical core in your system.

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#cpu) indicates that `--cpus` is actually a high level interface to the `--cpu-quota` option, which configures a quota of CPU time that the container is allocated per the time period specified by `--cpu-period`

Also, these Docker options appear to map directly to the [Linux kernel's CFS bandwidth control mechanism](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/scheduler/sched-bwc.html):

> CFS bandwidth control is a CONFIG_FAIR_GROUP_SCHED extension which
> allows the specification of the maximum CPU bandwidth available to a
> group or hierarchy.

So `--cpus 1.5` will give the container 1.5 cores worth of runtime every cpu-period.